# I'm a big fan of this riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

Next phrases all have an answer to them and all answers are related to each other, good luck!

> 1. they sail they drink and treasure is what they hanker,
>
>    But don't annoy them or they will f*** you with an anchor.
> 2. For history don't look far
>
>    as it is everything you want to learn about war.
> 3. known by a lot not to be seen
>
>    As batman would not be so keen.
> 4. I do not wish for something during the day
>
>    As hope is all that I will pay.
> 5. When everybody dies
>
>    The apocalypse will rise.

HINT:

3.

> The biggest hint actually comes from @Jannis being batmetal

5. (format is a bit odd, couldn't let the lines start on a new line in invisible block quotes... maybe someone can fix this :) ?)

> ```
> Adventures of different dimension
> ```
>
> ```
> Come together in a place where time is of no mention.
> ```

---

> ```
> One who cannot feel
> ```
>
> ```
> Put them through tests unreal.
> ```

---

> ```
> While this is all a hassle
> ```
>
> ```
> One thing lies ahead, the electric castle
> ```

EDIT: Only number 3 is still not found.

Final hint to find number 3:

> ```
> As time ticks at the klok to awaken
> ```
>
> ```
> The metal apocalypse is forsaken
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer :

1. They sail they drink and treasure is what they hanker,
   But don't annoy them or they will f*** you with an anchor.

   > This refers to [Alestorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alestorm), a scottish pirate-themed heavy metal band. One of their last album song refers to anchors and where you can put them.
2. For history don't look far as it is everything you want to learn about war.

   > This could be [Sabaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabaton_(band)), another metal band with a high interest in war history.
3. Known by a lot not to be seen As batman would not be so keen.

   > 
4. I do not wish for something during the day As hope is all that I will pay.

   > Probably [Nightwish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightwish), the name itself is quite explanatory. I recall one of their song has something to do with hope, but I didn't listen to them for a decade so my memories are a bit outdated.
5. When everybody dies The apocalypse will rise.

   > 

So my guess is

> That you are a big metal fan indeed ;)

Comment: Both would indeed be correct, don't think that 1 was very hard to find with your name :p.

Comment: Yes 4 is also correct as well as the link between each answer, and your memory is not failing you they have a song about hope. Though 3 and 5 are still to be found, they are my most favorites but also less known than the others

Comment: Is no.3 [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qatmJtIJAPw) ?

Comment: @Jannis Damn didn't think someone would get that reference so fast. The reference is correct but I'm looking for the original which is not that hard to find :p.

Comment: @mrdeadsven dunno whats the original, because someone just showed me like half a year ago this video. as I read the answer and batman I drew the connection. I am no real lover of metal. cool question though

Comment: Edguy's album Age of the Joker comes to mind for #3, but looks like that's not correct? A couple songs there seem almost appropriate. Love running into (power) metal fans!

Comment: @Harfatum nope it is also not that one, I'll probably add another hint tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, n°5 should definitely be...

> **Ayreon** ... But I do not understand how it matches with the firth hint....
>  Is it a reference to 'Y' (or '01011001') where human kind is the object of the "sixth extinction", which is also the final song of the album?

Comment: Yes you are correct it is ayreon. but I don't get what you are asking could you copy the sentence of my riddle that you don't understand so I can explain it?

Comment: @mrdeadsven it is about "When everybody dies The apocalypse will rise."

Comment: Ohh it was actually very simple. Everybody dies and Run apocalypse Run are my favorite songs of the band (and also 2 of the more known songs) And I choose these instead of into the electric castle to start with, because the electric castle is much older and I think lesser known at the moment. Also because what they are most known for is songs of the end of the world etc. so I thought a rising apocalypse was a good reference towards them.

Comment: Indeed! that was too obvious and I missed it! Fool of me :)

Comment: Yea I was like ohh they are far less known then all the rest let me just put in 2 known song titles so it's a bit fair, but seems putting things plain in the open in a puzzle site is the best way to hide things :p.

Answer (score 0):

Going with Keelhaul's theme of

> Metal bands

When everybody dies
The apocalypse will rise.

> This could be **Metallica**. The first line hints at *Kill 'Em All*, and the second line could refer to "My Apocalypse" or maybe "The Four Horsemen". Then again, both themes are staples of the genre so I wouldn't be surprised if there are multiple possible answers here.

Comment: I'm afraid a band like Metallica is a tiny bit too famous considering : "Though 3 and 5 are still to be found, they are my most favorites but also *less known than the others*" :p

Comment: Nice reasoning (and I do like me some Metallica :p ) but unfortunate not the correct answer here. As I said in the comment before the last 2 that you are looking for are less known and I think Metallica is pretty much one the most famous ones out there. I'll probably add a hint tomorrow, though I think that the comment of jannis was the biggest hint there is for 3.

Comment: Oh I see, hadn't noticed that comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add my contribution.

3. Known by a lot not to be seen As batman would not be so keen.

   > May it be "Avatar" (the band, indeed!)? The word avatar may match the first part of the description... and I don't know any song of them matching those words. But I am at least sure that Johannes Eckerström loves the "Joker" theme... which may match the batman part!... It may also be the answer to the 5th since "Apocalypse" is one of their thema, but I think the batman thing bears out my first impression

Comment: Another great band, I've seen them live for the first time last year very good performance, but also not the answer I was looking for neither for 3 or 5.